# Create a list of users with mailbox, MBsize, and OU with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting

I am trying to make export the output of the following commands to a csv, and then manually combine them. The goal is to create a list of users who have mailboxes, the mailbox size, and sort by OU. In this current state the output is garbled, starting with

```
#TYPE Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData
```

What is the correct way to export this table to an CSV? When I use out-file all the table output is in a single column. Is there a better more efficient method that I could be using?

```
get-mailbox -organizationalunit "ou=AA,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com" -resultsize unlimited | get-mailboxstatistics | ft DisplayName,TotalItemSize | export-csv X:\AA.csv
get-mailbox -organizationalunit "ou=LATAM,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com" -resultsize unlimited | get-mailboxstatistics | ft DisplayName,TotalItemSize | export-csv X:\France.csv
get-mailbox -organizationalunit "ou=Asia,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com" -resultsize unlimited | get-mailboxstatistics | ft DisplayName,TotalItemSize | export-csv X:\LATAM.csv
```

Helpful input is much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things to try. First, don't use `format-table`, that is strictly for creating formatted output for display, not for passing along the pipeline. Use `select-object` instead. Secondly, you could omit the type information output by `export-csv` by using the `-NoTypeInformation` switch. For example:

```
get-mailbox -organizationalunit "ou=AA,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com" -resultsize unlimited | get-mailboxstatistics | select DisplayName,TotalItemSize | export-csv X:\AA.csv -NoTypeInformation
```